# Download link is not working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm creating a project in Phonegap for Android. Everything is working fine except the downloading link. that same link is working fine in browsers but when I tried that app on mobile it's not working.
I checked in logs and I'm getting this.

[image]

I have put the link on an image like this

```
   <a href="'+clink+'"><img src="images/user-file/download.png" alt="img"></a>
```

**clink** is a var which is coming from jsonfile with link.

> **this is clink data**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First yous should install cordova white list plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist and then  add the following to `config.xml`

```
     <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

You can find `config.xml` under `platforms/android/res/xml` folder